# How to do xsd validation for incoming request when we have more than 1 url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on SpringBoot SOAP WS project, I have to do xsd validation for an incoming request, I have 3 WSDL(means 3 URLs to validate), but unfortunately, I am able to do one. in below code addInterceptors() have added hotelDirectUpdateSchema(), similar to this I have 2 more xsd.
How can I handle 3 request validation?

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WSConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/service/*");
    }
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
        validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(hotelDirectUpdateSchema());
        interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it below is the soloution

```
 @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        HotelDirectUpdateRQValidator validatingInterceptor = new HotelDirectUpdateRQValidator();
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(false);
        validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchemaCollection(new XsdSchemaCollection() {
            @Override
            public XsdSchema[] getXsdSchemas() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public XmlValidator createValidator() {
                try {
                    return XmlValidatorFactory.createValidator(getSchemas(), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Failed to create validator e={}", e);
                }
                return null;
            }

            public Resource[] getSchemas() {
                return new Resource[]{
                        new ClassPathResource("/schemas/OTA/OTA_HotelRateAmountNotifAndHotelAvailNotifRQValidate.xsd"),
                        new ClassPathResource("/schemas/HotelDirectUpdateRQ.xsd")
                };
            }
        });

        interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
    }
```